# MySQL удалить все записи, ссылающиеся на несуществующий в этой таблице ID

Tags: mysql, pdo, alias

Вот мой вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585932/mysql-delete-rows-that-have-parameter-which-refers-to-the-not-exist-id/46587654?noredirect=1#comment80132199_46587654
Но MySQL с PDO запрещают использовать алиасы в команде DELETE.

Вот таблица (примерная): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5255ff/1 и нужно удалить все записи, где поле `"for_id"<>0` и полю `"for_id"` нет соответствия поля `"id"` данной таблицы (`(8,3,2,'tom')` ссылается на несуществующий `id=3`).

Спасибо.

Comment: Мда, что то на английском SO совершенную ерунду ответили. MySQL не позволяет в where обращаться к той же таблице из которой идет удаление и алиасы и PDO тут совершенно не причем. там отвечу. тут закрываем по дублю ...

Comment: Да, жду с нетерпением. Хотя, "родной" мануал MySQL нигде не запрещает алиасы. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html

Comment: Ну так алиасы конечно работают, нельзя в not exists обращаться к той же таблице. зато в join  можно http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a2fed/1

Comment: Ну что сказать... Вы - гений! Спасибо!

Comment: Удалить вопрос?

Comment: Или пусть он будет "дорвеем" на тот развернутый вопрос с ответами.